# Creating a variable that is the value of the fifth of another variable, and if no value on fifth period, takes the closest

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, economics

I need help creating the variable 'NewVar' in the following dataset:

```
df2 <- read.table(
text =
"Year,Data,Country,NewVar,
1,3,US,NA,
3,NA,US,NA,
5,2,US,2,
7,7,US,NA,
10,NA,US,7,
1,3,UK,NA,
2,5,UK,NA,
3,4,UK,NA,
5,NA,UK,4,
10,6,UK,6,
", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

In other words, a variable that takes the fifth value of 'data' based on year and country.
In the case that no value is present in that specific period for that country, it will take on the closest value of the same country in the previous 5 years interval.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on how you expect your output to look like? By the way I'm getting an extra variable `X` from your data set.

Comment: I apologize about the variable X. It is a mistypo.
The output variable, NewVar, will take on the every fifth value of another variable. In other words, making the column named Data quinquennial. However due to limited data, there may no exist data for every 5 years so it has to take on the value from the closest year of that country. Preferably year 5, if not, year 4 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

One way of approaching this problem is to complement the missing data with a previous non-missing value. The package `{tidyr}` has a nice `fill()` function for this.

To demonstrate how it works, I store the results in Data2 and NewVar2. Feel free to overwrite your existing columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 %>% 
#------------ prepare the df, remove X and copy Data to Data2
  select(-X) %>% mutate(Data2 = Data) %>% 

#------------ use tidyr's fill to complement Data2
#------------ as we are interested in previous non-missing, use .direction="down"
  fill(Data2, .direction = "down") %>% 

#------------ check now every 5th year, if you need more %in% gives you freedom
  mutate(NewVar2 = case_when(
          Year %in% c(5, 10, 15) & !is.na(Data) ~ Data    # if value exists, take it
        , Year %in% c(5, 10, 15) & is.na(Data)  ~ Data2   # if not take alternative
        , TRUE ~ as.integer(NA))                          # set case_when default to NA
 )
```

This gives you:

```
   Year Data Country NewVar Data2 NewVar2
1     1    3      US     NA     3      NA
2     3   NA      US     NA     3      NA
3     5    2      US      2     2       2
4     7    7      US     NA     7      NA
5    10   NA      US      7     7       7
6     1    3      UK     NA     3      NA
7     2    5      UK     NA     5      NA
8     3    4      UK     NA     4      NA
9     5   NA      UK      4     4       4
10   10    6      UK      6     6       6
```